# Can I prevent pull requests being merged at certain times of the week?

Tags: git, github

On my GitHub repo, I have two primary branches, `develop` and `main`, which represent a testing and production-ready website, respectively. I work on a feature on some branch, say `newFeature`, and then I merge that into `develop`, for testing. Other people are also doing this with their branches, so then `develop` has a number of changes on it. Assuming everything is tested, we want to now add these changes to the production-ready site by merging `develop` into `main`.

I want to do this merge from `develop` to `main` regularly, say every Friday at 10am. I'll need to check in with anyone who has added changes this week, to ensure that everything is tested and working correctly. To ensure the chance of success here, **I'd like to prevent people from merging any more pull requests into `develop` after Thursday at 2pm**.

The devs (who are made aware of this restriction) should then spend the rest of the day testing any changes on `develop` that are due to be added to `main` the following morning. If they find any issue with what's already on `develop`, they can fix the issue on their branch, raise a PR into `develop`, and ask the repository owner (who is not subject to this restriction) to approve their PR.

Is this scenario, where users (except the repo owner) can't merge PRs into a branch at certain times of the week, possible?

Comment: Perhaps, but strategies that need code freezes to work are problematic and usually avoided. You might be better off by picking a different approach - branch from master, merge each feature back when it's done, TDD everything so developers don't have to have a separate testing phase.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I won't go into too much detail, but TDD would be hard to sell to the folks in charge of this repo. It's a pretty hefty codebase with very few maintainers, and from what I can see, adding unit tests and such would require a major overhaul of the website's structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to accomplish this, and none of them are even GitHub specific:

1. Lock down the `develop` branch starting a time X and ending at time Y. AFAIK most popular centralized Git repo tools have the ability for the admins to manually lock and unlock branches (either with an explicit lock or by adjusting permissions). Whether you can automate the timing would be tool dependent, but I assume you could write custom integrations, and if not, manually locking once per week isn't a big deal, especially since you would have to intervene manually to allow bug fixes to get in.
2. Add a custom integration "gated check-in" such that additional requirements exist during the desired time frame.
3. Don't lock down `develop` at all! This is actually what most people do. For example, in [Git Flow you simply create a release branch](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/#diagram) for this exact reason. If you don't want to actually create the dedicated release branch, you don't have to; just remember the commit ID from `develop` that you cutoff and tested from, and if you don't have new PRs for bug fixes, simply release that commit ID and merge that commit ID into `main`. If you end up having bug fixes, you might as well create a `release` branch so there is a branch to PR the fixes into.

Whether you use Git Flow or not, I highly recommend option 3, for sanity purposes, and so you don't have to stop development during the release cycle.

Comment: Thanks for all that detail. I'm definitely more drawn to option 3, as we're currently using git flow, just without the `release` branch. I can see now the value of using such a branch. A question though; if more than one person has to work on some bug fixes before `release` is merged to `main`, will they all have to work on the `release` branch? Will this cause any issue (e.g., merge conflicts)?

Comment: I'll also update the title of the question in line with your note, as that is the crux of my question really.

Comment: @MichaelMurphy yes, and it's fine for multiple people to work on bug fixes on the `release` branch simultaneously. It's certainly possible to have merge conflicts if two different PRs are modifying the same files, but this is expected and normal- the first person to complete their PR "wins", and the second person resolves the conflicts (perhaps by pulling in the first developer if they need help). It's no different than multiple people working on features in `develop` that touch the same files. It's just a normal part of collaboration.

Comment: @MichaelMurphy I removed that note from my answer now that it's no longer relevant.

Comment: Alright, I think that will handle my use case. Thanks!

Comment: @murchu27 I just re-read your comments and it occurred to me that I may have misunderstood your question: "...will they all have to work on the release branch?" In case this wasn't clear, in Git Flow, if you create a release branch, you should lock it down the same way you do for `develop` and `main`. Bug fixes for the release would be done on feature branches and PR'd into the `release` branch. If multiple people have PRs that need to go in, the second person could rebase their branch onto `release` to get the latest changes before completing their PR. (Just like they do with `develop`.)

Comment: thanks for the update, appreciate you coming back to this! We hadn't done that before, but I'll suggest that to the repo manager, thanks!

Comment: @TTT  from your first point "..most popular centralized Git repo tools have the ability for the admins to manually lock and unlock branches" could you please name such tools that I can use to `lock/unlock` a specific **github branch**?

Comment: @han in GitHub you just enable branch protection and temporarily make the rule(s) strict enough that no one can complete a PR. For example, you could temporarily require a status check that never passes.

Comment: @TTT so there is no essay way unlike bitbucket has `Prevent all changes` in github that can restrict PRs to be merged unless as you mentioned some kind of rules implied so it never pass and that restrict PRs

Comment: @han I know AzureDevOps literally has "lock branch" and sounds like BitBucket has something similar. Sounds like it isn't as straight forward in GitHub, though it can be created to act that way, I think.

Comment: @han side note, unless you are resetting a branch for some reason, you could use my #3 suggestion and never actually have to lock a branch.